# Any books that teach the science of Indian cooking?

Tags: food-science, cookbook, indian-cuisine

Can someone please suggest good books to understadn the science of Indian cooking ?

Comment: The science of cooking is the same no matter the cuisine.

Comment: Masala Labs by Krish Ashok

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in the new release [The Flavor Equation: The Science of Great Cooking Explained](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1452182698) by Nik Sharma, a molecular biologist from India. I haven't read it, but the table of contents, reviews, and the author's previous work suggest that it has a heavy emphasis on Indian cooking.